# Converting flat array into array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array called initialarray

```
var initialarray = new Array();
```

I have a variable and an object which needs to be pushed under the expansion of variable.

```
var initvar = "a";
```

> var employeeobjects

contains five employeeobjects with name and desc.

I am building in this way which is resulting in flattened array.

```
var empArray = [initvar];
empArray.push(employeeobjects);
initialarray.push(empArray);
```

which is resulting in

```
initarray: Array[1]
 >0 : Array[2]
   0:"a"
   1:Array[1] //employeeobjects
```

I need employeeobjects to come under `"a"` on expansion of "a". Can anybody please tell what modifications I need to make?

Edit:
The code goes like this:

```
var employeeobjects = [{
"name" : "a",
"desc" : "desc1"
},{
"name" : "b",
"desc" : "desc2"
}]


var initialarray = new Array();
var initvar = "a";
var empArray = [initvar];
empArray.push(employeeobjects);
initialarray.push(empArray);
```

The result should be:

```
initarray: Array[1]
 >0 : Array[2]
   0:"a"
    > 1:Array[1] //employeeobjects
```

"a" and employeeobjects should not be in same level. employeeobjects should come under "a"

Comment: please dont use new Array! use `var A = [];`

Comment: @TEST and why is that ?

Comment: You need an array of EmployeeObjects and your "a" is not really needed for that. Otherwise, you'd have to create an object with an "a" property that you then assign your EmployeeObject to.

Comment: `var A = new Array()` is slower than `var A = []` and the second way is more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need employeeobjects to come under "a" on expansion of "a". Can
>   anybody please tell what modifications I need to make?

Looks like you are looking for `a` to be an object rather than a simple literal text.

Try something like this

```
var initvar = "a";
var employees = {};
employees[initvar] = employeeobjects;
initialarray.push(employees);
```